# Почему возникает ошибка преобразования типов?

Tags: c++

```
void
CMy2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    UpdateData(true);
    int word_count;
    int word_letter;
    int letter_summ;
    CString main_temp;

    word_count = 0;
    word_letter = 0;
    letter_summ = 0;
    main_temp = m_in;

    for (int j = 0; j < main_temp.GetLength(); j++) {
        if (main_temp.Find(" ") >= 0) {
            word_count++;
            word_letter = main_temp.Find(" ");
            main_temp = main_temp.Right(main_temp.GetLength() -
                        main_temp.Find(" ") - 1);
        }
        letter_summ += word_letter;
        word_letter = 0;
    }
    letter_summ += main_temp.GetLength();
    word_count++;
    double temp;
    temp = double (letter_summ) / double (word_count);
    m_out.Format("Cреднее число букв в слове: %.3f", temp);
    UpdateData(false);
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> Не существует контекста, в котором такое преобразование возможно
> `c:\users\вовка\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\2\2\2dlg.cpp(184): error C2664: int ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>::Find(wchar_t,int) throw() const: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "const char [2]" в "wchar_t"
>          with
>          [
>              BaseType=wchar_t,
>              StringTraits=StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t>
>          ]`

Answer (score 4):

надо .Find(L' ') вместо .Find(" ")